# How do I setup Multiple Triggers for Cruisecontrol.NET?

Tags: svn, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I'm new to CruiseControl.net and am attempting to setup it up for a project I'm working on. The project is kept under subversion, but the whole project is made up of the core project, and several components, each one a separate subversion project, each with a trunk, possible branches and tags. I need to setup cruisecontrol.net so that a change in the main core project subversion folder as **well as any of the included components** triggers a build. Obviously if the commit consists of files committed to multiple components, I still only want one build. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible: Use Multi Source Control Block:

```
<sourcecontrol type="multi">
    <sourceControls>
        <svn>
            <trunkUrl>svn://foo</trunkUrl>
            <workingDirectory>c:\dev\foo</workingDirectory>
        </svn>
        <svn>
            <trunkUrl>svn://bar</trunkUrl>
            <workingDirectory>c:\dev\bar</workingDirectory>
        </svn>
    </sourceControls>
</sourcecontrol>
```

PITFALL: Note that sourcecontrol node changes from `<sourcecontrol type="svn">` to `<svn>`
if used inside Multi Source Control Block.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure each project includes its component dependencies via [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html). Then [configure](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html) CruiseControl.NET to check externals:

```
<checkExternals>True</checkExternals>
```

This has the added advantage that you can choose whether to follow the HEAD of the dependency components, or point the svn:externals to a fixed revision.