# CruiseControl.NET, SVN and multiple dependencies

Tags: .net, svn, cruisecontrol.net

I'm using CruiseControl.NET and devenv within the ccnet.config to automate the build of a VS 2005 .NET solution. The solution contains references to several projects, which are dependent on each other as well as a Library folder which contains third party dll's and other dll's compiled from projects I've created.

The problem I'm having is trying to setup my ccnet.config file to get the latest updates of each of the projects within the .NET sln file and Library folder from SVN before it begins the devenv task.

Can someone help or point me in the right direction as I can't seem to find anything on the web?

Below is my ccent.config file, I'm using PreProcessor's to avoid repetition as I will be reusing this for other solution files that are of similar structure:

```
<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">

  <cb:define MainTrunk="svn://mySvnUrl"/>
  <cb:define WorkingDir="C:\Svn\"/>
  <cb:define SvnExec="C:\Program Files\CollabNet Subversion Client\svn.exe"/>
  <cb:define ArtifactsDir="\Artifacts"/>

  <cb:define name="MyProjectName">
      <project name="$(ProjectName)"
               description="$(ProjectName) build">

        <triggers>
        <!-- check the source control every X time for changes, 
             and run the tasks if changes are found -->
          <intervalTrigger
                   name="continuous"
                   seconds="500"
                   buildCondition="IfModificationExists"
                   initialSeconds="5"/>
        </triggers>

        <sourcecontrol type="svn">

            <trunkUrl>$(MainTrunk)/$(ProjectName)/trunk</trunkUrl>

            <workingDirectory>$(WorkingDir)$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>

            <executable>$(SvnExec)</executable> 

        </sourcecontrol> 

        <tasks>
              <devenv>
                    <solutionfile>$(WorkingDir)$(ProjectName)\$(ProjectName).sln</solutionfile>
                    <configuration>Debug</configuration>
                    <executable>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\devenv.com</executable>
                    <!--<buildTimeoutSeconds>10</buildTimeoutSeconds>-->
                </devenv>

        </tasks>

        <publishers>
          <xmllogger />
          <artifactcleanup cleanUpMethod="KeepLastXBuilds"
                           cleanUpValue="50" />
        </publishers>

      </project>
    </cb:define>

    <cb:scope ProjectName="ProjectA">
        <cb:MyProjectName/>
    </cb:scope>

</cruisecontrol>
```

**UPDATE:** After asking the question, I started thinking that perhaps the way to tackle this is to check for modifications on the dependent projects and if there is a change, to then trigger the build of the VS solution file - ProjectA. So I've since updated my ccnet.config accordingly (see below). I will then apply this for the dependent projects within my VS sln as well.

Would still appreciate if someone could take a look and let me know if I am going in the right direction.

```
<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">
  <!-- This is your CruiseControl.NET Server Configuration file. Add your projects below! -->
  <cb:define MainTrunk="svn://SvnUrl"/>
  <cb:define WorkingDir="C:\Svn\"/>
  <cb:define SvnExec="C:\Program Files\CollabNet Subversion Client\svn.exe"/>
  <cb:define ArtifactsDir="\Artifacts"/>

  <cb:define name="MyProjectName">
      <project name="$(ProjectName)"
               description="$(ProjectName) build">

        <triggers>


          <projectTrigger project="Libraries">
            <triggerStatus>Success</triggerStatus>
            <innerTrigger type="intervalTrigger"
                          seconds="120"
                          buildCondition="ForceBuild" />
          </projectTrigger>

        </triggers>

        <sourcecontrol type="svn">

            <trunkUrl>$(MainTrunk)/$(ProjectName)/trunk</trunkUrl>

            <workingDirectory>$(WorkingDir)$(ProjectName)</workingDirectory>

            <executable>$(SvnExec)</executable> 

        </sourcecontrol> 

        <tasks>
              <devenv>
                    <solutionfile>$(WorkingDir)$(ProjectName)\$(ProjectName).sln</solutionfile>
                    <configuration>Debug</configuration>
                    <executable>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\devenv.com</executable>
                    <!--<buildTimeoutSeconds>10</buildTimeoutSeconds>-->
                </devenv>

        </tasks>

        <publishers>
          <xmllogger />
          <artifactcleanup cleanUpMethod="KeepLastXBuilds"
                           cleanUpValue="50" />
        </publishers>

      </project>
    </cb:define>

    <cb:scope ProjectName="ProjectA">
        <cb:MyProjectName/>
    </cb:scope>

    <project name="Libraries">
        <triggers>
          <intervalTrigger name="continuous" seconds="60"  buildCondition="IfModificationExists" initialSeconds="5"/>
        </triggers>
        <sourcecontrol type="svn">                      
            <trunkUrl>svn://SvnUrl/Libraries</trunkUrl>
            <workingDirectory>C:\Svn\Libraries</workingDirectory>
            <executable>C:\Program Files\CollabNet Subversion Client\svn.exe</executable>           
        </sourcecontrol> 
    </project>  

</cruisecontrol>
```

Comment: what problems do you experience when you use the mentioned config?

Comment: @metalheart - there's no problem with config, as in the build works but if I make a change to my Libraries folder and check into SVN, the build server won't get the latest version of the Libraries folder from SVN because it's not defined in the config. How do I tell it to get the latest Libraries folder and then trigger the build of ProjectA? Thanks.

Comment: is the Library folder inside or outside the project trunk?

Comment: outside the project trunk:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you include 3rd party libraries in each of your project roots via an [svn:externals](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html) property on the project trunk pointing to the library folder, use the following switch inside the `sourcecontrol` configuration block:

```
<checkExternals>True</checkExternals>
```

This way CC.NET triggers the compilation upon modifications in the library folder, too.

You might also need:

```
<checkExternalsRecursive>True</checkExternalsRecursive>
```

Comment: Thanks metalheart. Unfortunately I haven't configured my project root to include the 3rd party libraries via svn:externals. I've since modified the config and posted above. Do you think what I've proposed is feasible? Thanks.

Comment: @creativeincode: Seems OK to me (but you have to check for yourself), you might also be interested to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273619/how-do-i-setup-multiple-triggers-for-cruisecontrol-net/1276263#1276263) as an alternative (probably less complicated)